# how to add whitespace for text in a gui(checkers)

Tags: java

I already have the board for checkers but the border only goes along with the board itself. I want to add some white space to the right of the board where you can have text like score and nicknames. How exactly would i add that white space to have text on the side?

[image: here's what I have so far for the board]

---

This code is all in java :

```
public class CheckersApp extends Application {

   public static final int TILE_SIZE = 100; 
   public static final int WIDTH = 8; 
   public static final int HEIGHT = 8; 
   private Tile[][] board = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

   public void paintComponent (Graphics g) { 
        g.drawString( "Score: ", 30, 40 ); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please post your code that creates the checkerboard, and maybe what you've tried to create the whitespace.

Comment: public class CheckersApp extends Application {
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) 
    {
        g.drawString( "Score: ", 30, 40 );
    }
    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 100;
    public static final int WIDTH = 8;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 8;

    private Tile[][] board = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

Comment: thats what i have for the board itself

Comment: theres other code for the tiles and everything but the code above is just for the border length and width length of the board. Wondering how i would add space to the right for text without changing the board.

Comment: If you're drawing/painting everything, then you need to add an offset to leave some blank space on one side or the other. There should also be a way to take all your existing code and encapsulate it in a sub-view.